# Redacted information is still visible in non-edited posts

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, post-redaction

A couple of days ago I noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456028/the-operation-has-timed-out-http-request-timeout-was-set-to-30000ms-while-payp), which seemingly had valid OAuth credentials of some kind contained within it.  I flagged it for a moderator, and it was deemed helpful:

[image]

All good at this point, I figured I'd take another look at the question to see if anything else had happened.  When I got there, I could still see the token:

[image]

Seemed a bit odd, since my flag was marked helpful.  I clicked edit, and saw that it had indeed been replaced out in the source markdown, which was confirmed by viewing the post history:

[image]

Even from a logged out browser that had never been to that URL before, I could see the original post.  I figured it must be a caching thing, so edited the post once more, adding in an extra line - the live post is now properly redacted:

[image]

It seems that there might be a bug in the system where if you redact information in a revision, if that revision is still the current one, it is not updated/republished correctly.

Comment: Looks like it is gone now.  Do note that mods cannot by themselves redact the information.  It is a action they do and then it goes into a queue to be reviewed by other mods to make sure.  You may be seeing that delay.

Comment: @NathanOliver It only went after my subsequent edit on the question just now, forcing a refresh of the contents that are currently being displayed "live" for that question.

Comment: Also it should be pointed out if the sensitive information is still available in that other post this post will attract more attention to it and having it gathered by other people.

Comment: @JoeW It's not in the other post anymore.  It was up until I performed another edit - that's my bug report.

Comment: hmm. maybe the rev history needed to be re-rendered.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes - that's what I'm saying.  If the history entry that is being redacted is the one that is currently "live", it should be re-rendered/republished.

Comment: The bug seems to be that the redaction tool does not regenerate the (cached) HTML for a post, when a tag-only edit is the latest version. This *may* also manifest itself when a title-only edit is the latest version.

Comment: @Matt Right, so even more obscure then!