# Is there something beyond delete and close?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Closed and locked questions can be viewed by everyone. Deleted questions can be viewed by 10k rep users. Is there something beyond deletion that maybe only moderators can see? Or do posts ever get completely removed so that they cannot be restored?

Comment: Moderators can see deleted comments and user accounts. And lots more besides. But there is not really a stage for posts that goes beyond deletion, no. There is only “not deleted” and “deleted”.

Comment: In theory posts can be removed from the database entirely. That is an extremely rare occurrence. I think in the history of the site this hasn’t happened more than once or twice. Presumably they could still be restored from backups.

Comment: Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Comment: There is also a lock, I guess. Similar concept but different outcome.

Comment: @MartijnPieters out of the millions of questions ever posted, how come only one or two posts were ever permanently removed? I thought it was slightly more common than that (e.g someone accidentally posted sensitive information and asked mods/staff to remove it permanently)

Comment: @Chris such posts are not permanent-deleted, we redact those instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters also delete the edit history or anyone can access the information right?

Comment: Yes edit history gets redacted in such cases as well. Seen it happen once or twice myself

Comment: @weegee: redacting alters the edit history.

Comment: Note that the redaction system isn't itself [entirely bulletproof](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328949/redacted-information-is-still-visible-in-non-edited-posts)...

Comment: @Chris: the permanent deletion (or deletions? I'm only aware of [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131733/why-was-the-original-boat-programming-question-deleted)) occurred before the redaction system was implemented.

Comment: @MichaelMyers There might have been [another](https://twitter.com/stackoverflow/status/624575358306795522)...